# UK Postgraduate student loans for 2016-2017 intake

Tags: masters, funding, united-kingdom

The UK government announced that from 2016-2017 student loans for masters degree will be available up to a value of £10000.

I will complete a masters degree in August this year and I intend to do another masters degree starting in October this year.

Will I be eligible for these new student loans?

Or will only people who are doing their first masters be eligible?

Comment: I have heard of a rule saying that you cannot get funding for a second masters degree in the UK if you've already had funding for the first one (also in the UK). Not sure whether that applies to loans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UK rules on student loans are described [here](https://www.gov.uk/student-finance/who-qualifies).
Basically, it says that those doing their second masters are not eligible.